# Mina deploy task failing (simple kill process command)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, mina

I have a Mina task which should kill a process if it's running:

```
task :stop_queueing do
  queue! "pkill -f clockworkd || true"
end
```

When I try to execute it, this happens:

```
$ mina stop_queueing
  Connection to *** closed.

 !     Command failed.
       Failed with status 65280
```

Why is this failing? The rest of deployment process goes through just fine. If I run this command manually on server, there are no errors and the command exit code is in both cases 0 (whether clockworkd is running or not).

Comment: Does this command work outside of Mina, for instance when you do a manual deployment? If so, what code does it return?